# CFLoop and ListValueCount

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am tallying student evaluation of instructors.  I want my results to appear as:

```
Instructor1 -   145
Instructor2 -    23
Instructor3 -   394
```

The #CountInstructor# is not changing.  It is only the first count is correct.

Using Coldfusion 8.
Thanks for your help.

```
<CFQUERY NAME="GetAll" datasource="eval" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT ID, Instructor, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6
FROM data
</CFQUERY>
<CFQUERY NAME="GetInstructor" datasource="eval" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT DISTINCT Instructor
FROM data
ORDER BY Instructor
</CFQUERY>

<cfset myInstructor = ValueList(GetInstructor.Instructor)>
<cfset myCountInstructor = ValueList(GetAll.Instructor)>
<cfset CountInstructor = ListValueCount(myCountInstructor, myInstructor)> 

<cfoutput query="GetAll">
  <cfset CountInstructor = ListValueCount(myCountInstructor, GetInstructor.Instructor)> 
  #GetInstructor.Instructor#  - #CountInstructor# <br />
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: err ok... so whats the problem?

Comment: You don't need `dbtype="ODBC"` on your queries.  Apart from 'query', all other uses of dbtype are deprecated.

Comment: The #CountInstructor# is not changing.  It is only the first count is correct.

Comment: Seems like you could get the data directly from a single query instead of two different ones. If you give us more details about your tables, we could help get your query structured the way you need it.

Comment: Data is simple.  Instructor (formatted as: last first (no comma) (possible 50 choices from a drop down so all spelled the same.  Questions (Q1, Q2, etc.) only contains (Strongly Agree, Agree, Neutral, Disagree, Strongly Disagree, Blank (put in hidden option for blank, so it could be counted))  Each instructor will be listed in the data a hundred times or more.  I am wanting to count how many times the instructors name appears.

Comment: Found my mistake:  <cfoutput query="GetAll">
should be <cfoutput query="GetInstructor">
Getting correct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of ListValueCount(), within your query output loop, isn't helping you any. What is it you're trying to do exactly? If all you're looking to do is output a count as you go...

```
<cfoutput query="GetInstructor">
    #GetInstructor.Instructor# - #GetInstructor.CurrentRow#
</cfoutput>
```

Otherwise, I'm just not sure what you want to do (and you need to scope all of the variables, including the query names).

Comment: Found my mistake: <cfoutput query="GetAll"> should be <cfoutput query="GetInstructor"> Getting correct numbers

Comment: you might want to group the output by instructor to make that work the way OP wanted it to

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfoutput query="GetInstructor">
   <cfset CountInstructor = ListValueCount(myCountInstructor, GetInstructor.Instructor)> 
    #GetInstructor.Instructor#  - #CountInstructor# <br />
</cfoutput>
```